# How to set background color using Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

This should be a simple matter but for some reason it simply is not working.

**In my controller:**

```
$scope.projects = [ //...
    { background: "#ffffcc" }, 
    //... 
];
```

**In the HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="project in projects" 
     ng-style="{'backgroundColor': project.background}">
</div>
```

If I sub out `project.background` with `'#ffffcc'` it will work. I have also tried with `background-color` with no success. As well as `{{project.background}}`

Comment: Works fine [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6NfwZ8KCxk9nnH014FpU?p=preview)

Comment: why dont use directives, and why are you using inline css by the way?

Comment: you need to use it like, project.background, in the scope

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
<div ng-init="styles=[{backgroundColor: 'red', width:'100px', height: 'auto', display: 'block'}]">

<div ng-repeat="test in styles" ng-style="test">
.test {
    background-color: {{ test.backgroundColor }};
    display: {{ test.display }};
    width: {{ test.width }};
    height: {{ test.height }};
    }
</div>
```

You can also use the attributes in your controller like;

```
$scope.styles= [{
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width:'100px',
    height: 'auto',
    display: 'block'}];
```